# Is it possible to show ppt/pptx as aslide show using uidocumentcontroller in IOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, powerpoint, uidocumentinteraction

I have a requirement where i need to present documents like pdf/doc/docx/ppt/pptx on the ipad. Rather than showing the document in one page with vertical scroll, i need to show that as slides moving from left to right ( horizontal swipe ).. Can you tell me how i can accomplish that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The framework does not really offer a way of controlling how things are rendered once you pass the data to it.

Your best bet is to pre-process the files and handle the scrolling yourself by showing each page individually and implementing your own scrolling.